# A keyboard shortcut for the "status menu" in GNOME 3

Tags: linux, keyboard, gnome, shutdown, gnome3

Is there a keyboard shortcut, or can a keyboard shortcut be defined, to open the GNOME 3 "status menu" (the one in the upper right corner with your name on it that you use to log out, restart or shut down the machine)?

I want to be able to reboot or shut down the machine without using the mouse. In GNOME 2 I could do Alt+F1 and a short arrow key sequence, and now I want something similar.

Terminal is not an option - the GUI already has the necessary permissions and I want to take advantage of that, not `sudo shutdown -h`.

Comment: On Arch Linux, you can simply press Alt+F2 and type poweroff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To jump to the status bar or the desktop use: <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + TAB</kbd>

You could also set up the power button to popup the shutdown menu using `gnome-control-center power`.

Comment: I found out about the ctrl-alt-tab, but it was a lot of tabbing/arrows from there to the menu. Plus, in fallback mode, I switch to it, and several tabs after that, the focus seems to have disappeared - nothing happens if I press tab, enter, spacebar, windows and arrows.

The power button, however, does it for me. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Super-M (simultaneously Windows key and M key) takes me the top-menu on Ubuntu 18.04.01 - use arrows to navigate to status menu - acts similar to how Alt-F10 used to on 14.04. Also on some laptops the power button shows a shutdown menu (although for some reason it now just shuts down with my current config).

Answer (score 2):

I found this exchange while looking for the same thing. I don't really love any of the answers above (the accepted answer doesn't even work for me in gnome 3.28.2) so I'll add to what I've found.

`poweroff` is the closest; it's a command I never knew existed and is nice to know about; but in my opinion, I don't like that there is no confirmation.

I found the program `gnome-session-quit` which seems to handle all the functions of the status menu you're talking about. By default it will just pop up a window for logging out in 60 seconds, or immediately if you click yes, or the ability to cancel.

Furthermore, it has logout, power-off, and reboot.

```
Usage:
  gnome-session-quit [OPTION…] 

Help Options:
  -h, --help       Show help options

Application Options:
  --logout         Log out
  --power-off      Power off
  --reboot         Reboot
  --force          Ignoring any existing inhibitors
  --no-prompt      Don’t prompt for user confirmation
```

So, it appears the best option I've found so far is to go to [keyboard shortcuts](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en) in gnome and [create a custom shortcut](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en#custom) to `gnome-session-quit --power-off` and/or `gnome-session-quit reboot`.

I found this document [Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts) which talks about "PowerOff" being *Super-F4*, it doesn't seem to be implemented yet; however, I really like the idea of that being the shortcut inline with the rest of the window management through the super key in gnome3 - so I would recommend that key.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal *is* an option. You can call ConsoleKit over DBus, the same way GNOME does.

```
dbus-send --system --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" \
    /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

To reboot, use the `.Restart` method instead of `.Stop`.

---

To suspend or hibernate, call UPower:

```
dbus-send --system --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" \
    /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

(Same for `.Hibernate`.)

Comment: Thanks for correcting my ignorance. The commands you suggest aren't what I was after, but they do hint up some possibilities. I'll have to look into DBus sometime.

Comment: @Lyubomir: To quote your question, "What I want is to be able to reboot or shut down the machine without using the mouse."